# Compare two list with same length and remove by specific value

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I have two lists with the same length, both have 9 items

```
listA = ["spain","italy","germany","brazil","france","argentina","peru","bolivia","giappone"]
listB = [0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0]
```

I'd like to get listA without value '1' from listB:

```
listA = ["spain", "italy","argentina","giappone"]
```

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 4):

This is quite a good use case for [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress). With the difference that we need to invert the *binary* values of the selectors, otherwise it would be *the* perfect use case :)

```
from itertools import compress

list(compress(listA, map(lambda x: 1-x, listB)))
# ['spain', 'italy', 'argentina', 'giappone']
```

Or for a simpler approach in this case you can use `zip`:

```
[x for x,y in zip(listA,listB) if not y]
# ['spain', 'italy', 'argentina', 'giappone']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `zip`.

```
listA = ["spain","italy","germany","brazil","france","argentina","peru","bolivia","giappone"]
listB = [0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0]
out=[x for x,y in zip(listA,listB) if y==0]
```

Comment: Glad I helped you. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
listA = ["spain", "italy", "germany", "brazil",
         "france", "argentina", "peru", "bolivia", "giappone"]
listB = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
i = -1
for item in listB:
    i += 1
    if item == 0:
        print(listA[i])
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function? It is more idiomatic and will save you maintaining that `i` variable: `for i, item in enumerate(listB):`

Comment: yes i know but i did n't get at that point thanks for remembering

Answer (score 0):

Just use `zip` :)

```
listA = ["spain", "italy", "germany", "brazil", "france", "argentina", "peru", "bolivia", "giappone"]
listB = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]

getCountries = [i for (i,j) in zip(listA, listB) if j==0]  
'''
  i being all the countries and j being the value 0 or 1
  in this case gets all the countries only for j == 0 or you could do j != 1
'''
print(getCountries)
```

Output:

```
['spain', 'italy', 'argentina', 'giappone']
```